# cannot re-install firefox on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-11.04

I have uninstalled Firefox from my laptop. I am using Ubuntu 11.04. When I again try to install firefox by sudo apt-get install, it is giving following errors:

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main firefox i386 16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1
404  Not Found

Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main firefox i386 16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 404  Not Found

Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main firefox-globalmenu i386 16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-globalmenu_16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

When I try to update by sudo apt-get update, then also most of the links are coming as 404 not found. Please help me to fix the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your release has reached end of life (EOL), you need to modify /etc/apt/sources.list. Replace CODENAME with the codename of Ubuntu release that you are using.

```
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```